# ID sci fi short story, golden age. Simple man is picked to pass test to leave earth to expand and explore for humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, psychic

Earth is sending its best and brightest to prosper in space leaving the rest behind. A simple worker is given the opportunity to train while working for a group that wants to get him into the program. Climax is that he's a borderline simpleton who has been helped by three other individuals who want to leave but are physically compromised but psychically empowered.

Comment: Theodore Sturgeon, maybe?